# Swift Firebase TableView cannot remove last element

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a tableview that populates an array. I am able to add to firebase and the tableview reloads to show the newly added object. If I have 5 items in firebase then I would have 5 on the tableview. I am able to remove items from firebase through code and reload the tableview and it works great.

My issue is when I am on the last item on firebase and tableview and I delete that last item, the firebase removes it just fine, but the tableview keeps the last item but grays it out.

The app doesn't crash it just stays there until I add something back in.

Obviously if I tap on that grayed out cell my app crashes because I am tapping an index out of range.

Is there some code that I need to add to prevent this grayed out cell and just have an empty tableview?

[image: evidence]

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return serviceArray.count
  }


  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "serviceCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! ServiceTableViewCell

    let row = indexPath.row


    //    cell.serviceLogoImage.image = UIImage.init(named: serviceArray[row].serviceUrl!)

    cell.serviceNameLabel.text = serviceArray[row].serviceName 

    if serviceArray[row].serviceStatus == true {

      cell.serviceStatusView.backgroundColor = .green

    } else {

      cell.serviceStatusView.backgroundColor = .red

    }

    return cell
  }
```

I must be missing a small conditional because other than this the tableview works perfectly with firebase...

**Edit 1**

I have added the code used to populate the tableview

```
var serviceArray: [ServiceClass] = []


func pullCardData() {

serviceArray.removeAll()

let cardRef = ref.child("cards")

cardRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

  for cards in snapshot.children {

    let allCardIDs = (cards as AnyObject).key as String

    if allCardIDs == self.cardID {

      let thisCardLocation = cardRef.child(self.cardID)

      thisCardLocation.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        let thisCardDetails = snapshot as FIRDataSnapshot

        let cardDict = thisCardDetails.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        self.selectedCard.cardID = thisCardDetails.key
        self.selectedCard.nickname = cardDict["nickname"] as! String
        self.selectedCard.type = cardDict["type"] as! String

        self.cardNickNameLabel.text = cardDict["nickname"] as? String ?? ""

        let thisCardServices = self.ref.child("cards").child(self.cardID).child("services")
        let serviceRefLoc = self.ref.child("services")

        thisCardServices.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {serviceSnap in

          if serviceSnap.hasChildren() {

            for serviceChild in serviceSnap.children {

              let serviceID = (serviceChild as AnyObject).key as String

              serviceRefLoc.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {allServiceSnap in

                if allServiceSnap.hasChildren() {


                  for all in allServiceSnap.children {


                    let allServs = (all as AnyObject).key as String

                    let thisServiceLocationInServiceNode = self.ref.child("services").child(serviceID)

                    if serviceID == allServs {

                      thisServiceLocationInServiceNode.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {thisSnap in

                        let serv = thisSnap as FIRDataSnapshot

                        let serviceDict = serv.value as! [String: AnyObject]

                        let aService = ServiceClass()


                        self.serviceCurrent = serviceDict["serviceStatus"] as? Bool
                        self.serviceName = serviceDict["serviceName"] as? String
                        self.serviceURL = serviceDict["serviceURL"] as? String
                        self.serviceFixedBool = serviceDict["serviceFixed"] as? Bool
                        self.serviceFixedAmount = serviceDict["serviceAmount"] as? String


                        aService.serviceUrl = serviceDict["serviceURL"] as! String

                        aService.serviceName = serviceDict["serviceName"] as! String

                        aService.serviceStatus = serviceDict["serviceStatus"] as? Bool


                        aService.serviceID = serviceID


                        self.serviceArray.append(aService)

                        self.tableView.reloadData()


                      })
                    }
                  }
                }
              })
            }
          }
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

}

**Edit 2**

I had the idea to check if the firebase node even exits (it shouldn't since I just deleted it. SO

```
  func checkIfDataExits() {

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

  if snapshot.hasChild("services") {

    self.pullCardData()

  } else {
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
    print("no childen")
  }

})
}
```

As expected since I don't have the firebase node there anymore it prints "no children" but it still shows that last tableview cell....so

Comment: Can you show us the code that fills your serviceArray please ?

Comment: @Grifas, yes one second allow me to edit the question

Comment: Which firebase method do you use to fetch data from firebase ?

Comment: I start the fun with serviceArray.removeAll() because everytime I ADDED a service it would duplicate the array

Comment: @Grifas I know the func is crazy long, I'm working on trying to spit it up

Comment: and when you delete the last cell, how many numberOfRowsInSection returns ?

Comment: I am not sure how to check, I have a print(serviceArray.count) and it fires when I have 3, 2, 1, but when I delete the last item it does not print anything nor does hit the breakpoint

Comment: ok I have may be a solution but before can you show the didSelectRowAt please ?

Comment: I am not deleting the item in the array on this VC...the values are removed from Firebase on another VC and then I am sent back to THIS VC where the function that calls from Firebase ..deletes the array and then repopulates it, so the array should be empty and since there is nothing to pull down it should not put anything into the array....if I rerun the app with nothing in the firebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, my last edit was one line of code off from being what I needed.

Instead of

```
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

I replaced it with

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

So (without retying that long method) I simply wrote another method

```
  func checkIfDataExits() {

    serviceArray.removeAll()

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

      if snapshot.hasChild("services") {

        self.pullCardData()

      } else {

        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }

    })
  }
```

And THIS method decides wether or not to even run that long one

Answer (score 0):

resolve:

```
serviceArray.removeAll()
```

Code:

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

      if snapshot.hasChild("services") {

        self.pullCardData()

      } else {
        //code here
        serviceArray.removeAll()
        self.tableView.reloadData()
      }

    })
```